# Database and ERP

Tags: sql, database, erp

I am trying to master a new ERP application. I have good functional knowledge and I was advised to learn SQL. I do not know where to start. I have two books, SQL for Dummies and Database Development for Dummies, Which book should I read first? The idea is to get a good understanding of the relationship between ERP and database and to understand the database concepts in the context of an ERP application

---

Hi HLGEM and others I will be working in the roles of production support consultant and will be participating in an upgrade project.

Prod support: We get issues from the client site and we use SQL to find the necessary information. Upgrade Project: We will be upgrading to the newest version. I think we will have to migrate the data and do some configuration. Can you help me in planning what to learn? My colleagues suggested that I need to understand the tables, schemas, ERDs. Is that what I should be focusing on?

Comment: I suppose those are good introductions to learning SQL, but they are _not_ good for an introduction to ERP. You'd do better studying the literature of the specific ERP system you'll be using.

Comment: I have a good understanding of ERP but I need to know the role of dtabases in ERP like how are they used?what happens in a database when a transaction is carried out by an end user for ex: how is inventory updated when you receive goods?

But I precisely do not know the reason why I am asked to learn SQL by my colleague.How is SQL used when dealing with an ERP?

I think we use oracle SQL developer.Hope this helps a little bit in clarifying my question

Comment: We're using SAP for ERP here. The entire system is built on top of an Oracle database and uses a Java front-end. I suppose if you have access to the table schemas (we do not), it would be possible to perform queries against the data via some SQL tool. If that's the case, and you're aware, as you said, of how your ERP works, then it's possible that you'll get some useful information from those books. They'll tell you how to query the data. After that, you'll just need to know what tables and columns you need to access to grab the data you need.

Comment: Thanks Michael you are absolutely right . we have access to the table schemas.

But by seeing the links for TOC can you suggest which book to read first?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a DBA for your ERP? I would start by talking to them. You will need to learn two things; SQL and your ERP's data structures.

1) SQL - if you are just starting out have a look at O'Reilly's books. I haven't read either but [Learning SQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520830/) and [Headfirst SQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526849/) would be a good start. The Headfirst ones are very good practical ways of learning a new topic.

2) Your ERP data structure. You'll need a data dictionary and whatever documentation you can get hold of. You need to remember that between you and the database there is usually a ton of business logic that you'll need to recreate with your SQL when trying to access data. I would start with an area you are very familiar and build your SQL around that to learn some of the conventions. Remember that your ERP has probably been built over decades with 100's of people working on it so there will be many oddities and inconsistencies in there.

Sometimes SQL is the fastest way to get data from your ERP.. but have you investigated whether your ERP exposes it's business objects for .Net or COM or even Java? This is usually the way you'll need to go if you wish to put data into your ERP, or be assured that the data you retrieve from your ERP is correct.

Comment: Hey mark...I went to barnes&nobles and bought the headfirst sql book.Yes it is really good for beginners.Thanks

Regarding your second point I was not able to understand all of that.hopefully that should change once I complete this book.

Answer (score 1):

> what happens in a database when a transaction is carried out by an end user for ex: how is inventory updated when you receive goods?

I don't know about the Oracle equivalent but in SQL Server databases we can run Profiler to see exactly what was sent to the databases when a particular part of the application is run. This is invaluable in trying to fugure out some of the types of questions you have. I'm sure Oracle has some equivalent way to do the same thing or there are other products inthe the marketplace that do that, but I don't know what they are. I just throw out the idea to give you a a type of tool to be looking for.

You need to understand SQL because all ERPS are data intensive and you cannot understand what is going on in the database without understanding SQL. Remember Oracle has it's own flavor of SQL which is very differnt from other databases. So in learning make sure you learn PL/SQL. If the ERP was designed for multiple database backends, it may have used ANSII standard SQL instead of the more robust PL/SQL. If you don't understand both SQL and the theory of relational database design, you really don't understand ERP at all as the database is the most critical part of an ERP system. ERP database queries are generally quite complicated. At a minumum you need to thoroughly understand relational design, all types of joins and far more than the basic level CRUD operations.

What types of tasks are you go ing to be supporting in your ERP? This might lead to more and better suggestions of what to learn. For instance if you need to create custom reporting or data warehouse applications from the ERPs data, that is very different than just keeping the system running as an admin. If you are going to do performance tuning, you need to advance very quickly beyond the basics. This is advanced stuff that requires years of expertise to do well. There are also whole books on performance tuning but if you are looking at the "For Dummies" books, then you are not yet ready to understand them.

Comment: "You need to understand SQL because all ERPS are data intensive and you cannot understand what is going on in the database without understanding SQL"-----I completely agree with that.

I know the basic concepts and things like relational design.

Unfortunately I do not know my duties precisely.But I will get back to you once I have this information.

Comment: Hi HLGEM and others

I will be working in the roles of production support consultant and will be participating in an upgrade project.

Prod support:
We get issues from the client site and we use SQL to find the necessary information.

Upgrade Project:
We will be upgrading to the newest version.I think we will have to migrate the data and do some configuration.

Can you help me in planning what to learn? My colleagues suggested that I need to understand the Tables,schemas,ERDs.Is that what I should be focusiin on?

Please elaborate depending on your Time constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I read Develop ERP software (using .Net technology). The application is based on layered architecture. The contents is available [here](http://www.vkinfotek.com/develop-erp-software.html)